# What is the `connection` parameter of MapperExtension in sqlalchemy?

Tags: connection, sqlalchemy, mapper

The class `MapperExtension` has some methods, and `before_insert`, `before_update`, ... all have a parameter `connection`.

```
def before_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance):
```

I've read the documents of `MapperExtension`, but found nothing about this `connection`. What is it? And how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an instance of [`Connection` class](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection). Recent versions of SQLAlchemy distribution have examples directory, see [examples/nested_sets/nested_sets.py](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/393470c7abf1b1e0c32f037e0ed1eb8e8ce82543/examples/nested_sets/nested_sets.py?at=master#cl-32) to get an idea on how to use it in mapper extension.