# Column with default checking same table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy, I'd like to autogenerate an identifier for a model:

```
class Foo(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, default=datetime.now)
    reference = Column(Unicode, default=generate_reference)
```

Basically, I want `generate_reference` returning a field like:

```
FOO201410-001
```

where `2014` is current's year, `10` current's month and `001` the next id for current month, calculated using a query such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM foo
 WHERE strftime('%m', datetime(date, 'unixepoch')) == strftime('%m', date('now'))
   AND strftime('%y', datetime(date, 'unixepoch')) == strftime('%y', date('now'))
```

I've taken the syntax form from what I've read from SQLite3, though it's just an example. Basically, I want to know how many other records have the same month/year, and assign the last part with that count.

I've tried doing defaults with [select expressions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#selecting), but as my table is not yet created, it looks like I cannot create a select expression from it yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with default instead of event:

```
def foo_reference_default(context):
    now = datetime.now()
    month, year = now.month, now.year
    ref = context.connection.execute(db.select([Foo.__table__]).where(
        db.and_(db.extract('month', Foo.date)==month,
                db.extract('year', Foo.date)==year)
    ).count()).scalar() + 1
    return u'FOO{year}{month}-{ref:03}'.format(year=year, month=month, ref=ref)


class Foo(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, default=datetime.now)
    reference = Column(Unicode, default=foo_reference_default)
```

This is effectively the same as your answer: A prior SELECT is done in order to populate the INSERT. (Note that I added +1 so it would start at 001 instead of 000.)

You could, of course, use a lambda to embed the function into default, but I don't recommend it -- you only want to call now() once. Calling it multiple times introduces a slim but real chance of getting inconsistent data on month and year edges.

Comment: that question is from a project I'm not currently working on, so I cannot check whether I did test such strategy and I had issues with that. But it looks like answering my question quite well ;-)

Comment: About the use of a double datetime within a lambda, I believe it's fine whenever the target usage of the application makes it unlikely to be triggering it at exactly midnight at the end of a month and/or a year.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution that works fine, thanks to [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621013/1290438) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646773/what-is-the-connection-parameter-of-mapperextension-in-sqlalchemy):

```
class Foo(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, default=datetime.now)
    reference = Column(Unicode)

@db.event.listens_for(Foo, 'before_insert')
def receive_before_insert(mapper, connection, foo):
    ref = foo.query.filter(db.and_(db.extract('month', Foo.date)==datetime.now().month,
                                           db.extract('year',  Foo.date)==datetime.now().year)
                                              ).count()
    foo.reference = 'FOO{year}{month}-{ref:03}'.format(year=datetime.now().year,
                                                       month=datetime.now().month,
                                                       ref=ref)
```

though, I'm leaving the question open, in case someone suggests something that could
be directly embedded within the `default` key.